# How to compare two strings in c++ and work with default functions?

Tags: c++

I am working on my first ever c++ code and i am having some diffuclties the strcmp function couldn't be resolved!! Even though i did in h file: `using std::string;` I am working with Eclipse, so I did an h and cpp files in the h file i have this :

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <set>

using std::set;
using std::string;

namespace AA{
namespace BB{


    typedef enum{
        EASY , MEDIUM, HARD
    } Difficulty;

    class FIRST{
    private:
        char* name;
        Difficulty difficulty;

    public:       
        FIRST(const std::string& name, const Difficulty& difficulty);

        FIRST(const FIRST& first) = default;




    };
} // end of namespace BB
} 

// end of namespace AA
```

and in the cpp file I did this but i get eror that

> Function `strcmp` could not be resolved 'strcmp' is not a member of 'std'

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <set>
#include "Enigma.h"
#include <stdbool.h>

AA::BB::FIRST(const std::string& name, const Difficulty& difficulty):
    difficulty(difficulty),  name(name) {
}


bool AA::BB::FIRST::operator==(const FIRST& first) const{
    if((difficulty==(FIRST.difficulty))&&(strcmp(name,first.name)==0)){
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

Comment: You could search the web for some documentation on `strcmp`. That would probably tell you which header file you need to include. But you probably don't need `strcmp` at all, just compare `std::strings` using `==`.

Comment: std::string has the == operator implemented so compare them as you would with ints

Comment: question: i havethis right : char* name; in class FIRST
    private, but i get this error : 'char* AA::BB::FIRST::name' [-Wreorder]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why compare with `strcmp`, when you can make use of the existing `==` operator:

```
bool AA::BB::FIRST::operator==(const FIRST& first) const{
    if((difficulty == FIRST.difficulty) && (name == first.name)){
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

Or you could use its compare function which would yield the same result:

```
bool AA::BB::FIRST::operator==(const FIRST& first) const{
    if((difficulty == FIRST.difficulty) && (name.compare(first.name) == 0){
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

When you want to use a certain function you can go to some [reference site](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/strcmp), find out which header should be included in order to use this function (`<cstring>` in this case) and then include it.

You should also figure out the code style you are using. CAPS names are typically only used for macros (because they are evil).

Comment: what CAPS name ??

Comment: By CAPS I mean Caps Lock. Names such as `FIRST`, `AA`, `BB` etc.

Answer (score -1):

The function strcmp is C. There are no strings as you know them from C++.
See here: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstring/strcmp/

You could do:

```
#include <string>

int main()
{
    std::string name = "Webber";
    std::string firstName = "John";

    if (strcmp(name.c_str(), firstName.c_str()) == 0)
        ...
}
```

This will copy your C++ String to an char-Array

Comment: The `strcmp` function is also C++.  The C++ language does support null terminated sequences of characters, a.k.a. C-Style strings.

Comment: If you are going to use C++ `std::string`, you should make use of `operator ==` or the [`std::string::compare`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/compare) method.